# Fading previous frame doesn't fade all the way to black?

Tags: fragment-shader

I'm working on a 2D OpenGL program. It'll be a fairly simple fireworks visual.

So far what I have is that I draw a circle with a gradient "glow" to it and move it around on the screen. I want it to have a tail behind it as it moves so instead of calling glClear between each frame, I'm drawing a black quad over the whole screen with transparency in hopes of darkening the previous frame before drawing the next frame. I've got a decent tail on it but I've noticed the tail doesn't completely blend to black.

[image]

Currently the red glow moves up the screen and when it goes off the top it instantly moves back down to the bottom to make another pass. You can see that there's a "shadow" of where the ball has been before and it never gets darker.

I have a feeling it has something to do with the blend function. Here's what I currently have:

```
gl.BlendFunc(gl.SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)
```

I'm using [go-gl](https://github.com/go-gl/gl) but it is equivalent to

```
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)
```

Here's the shader that draws the circle and the quad:

```
#version 430 core

layout(location = 0) out vec4 color;
uniform float radius;
uniform vec2 center;
uniform float windowHeight;
uniform vec4 in_color;
uniform int gradient;

void main()
{
  if (gradient == 1) {
    vec2 correctedCenter = vec2(center.x, windowHeight - center.y);
    vec2 p = (gl_FragCoord.xy - correctedCenter) / radius;
    float r = sqrt(dot(p, p));

    if (r < 1.0) {
      color = mix(in_color, vec4(0, 0, 0, 0), r);
    } else {
      color = vec4(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
  } else {
    color = in_color;
  }
}
```

For the circle I use `gradient = 1` but for the quad I use `0`.

Answer (score 1):

Well sure, if you think about it, multiplying the previous value by a value > 0 will always leave some left over. So if you are multiplying the previous frame by, say, 0.5, it won't ever reach 0 (though practically speaking, once you pass the precision of the machine you'll effectively hit 0). Your options are to make the amount of the previous frame you're mixing in much less so it reaches 0 (by surpassing the precision of the GPU) faster, or keeping the past few positions and blending them with some set values. Like blend in the last 3 position at 25%, 50%, and 75% with the current frame. Or something along those lines.

Comment: I did expect it would take a long time to break precision and hit zero but I also expected the minuscule numbers to appear blacker than #050000 (at least that's what an eye dropper from the image above produces). Right now I'm rendering to a texture and rendering that texture to the screen. I've fixed this by modifying the shader that draws the texture to the screen but I'm not 100% happy with this.